# Camera face guideline

Tags: ios

What is the name of this camera face guideline?
I want to implement a similar one what keyword should I search for?
How do I implement this? Do I have to create a custom camera class or is there a simple solution?

Here is an example picture:

[image]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about user interfaces. It also is too broad.

Comment: Please read about [**How to Ask questions here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Generally, you should limit your questions to one question, and you should provide code that you have tried that isn't working. "How do I *x*?" will almost always get closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this with a [`cameraOverlayView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImagePickerController/cameraOverlayView) on `UIImagePickerController`.